# Derivative rule question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

In this image,from a website on compound interest derivations, why are you allowed to take the derivative of JUST the limit?  Shouldn't you have to take the derivative of the lefthand side of the equation as well as $ln(P)$,  Not just the limit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is evaluated using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

As we are evaluating the limit, it is applied to it only.